# Delete files with regular expression with negation

Tags: bash, unix, regex, find

Tried to create a script to delete files from the directory in a first script argument that does not contain a sequence of symbols in a second script argument. But It doesn't do a thing.
What I tried:

```
find $1 -name !\(.*$2.*\) | tee file | cat
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Well, first thing first, `-name` is a substring, not regex, match. Try `-regex` or `-iregex` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-regex` for a regex, not `-name`. Use `-!` or `-not` for negation:

```
find "$1" -not -regex ".*$2.*"
```

Quoting the variables should be safer than using them unquoted.

Comment: Wow. It works. -regex, heh...